# Не работает английская раскладка в редакторе юнити

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

В юнити до этого всё работало хорошо, но недавно вдруг перестал работать ввод каких-либо символов, если стоит английская раскладка (числа и прочие символы также не работают, но бекспейс, делит и подобные работают), на русской раскладке всё работает.
Может кто-то сталкивался? Вроде уже весь гугл прошерстил, ничего даже близко похожего не смог найти.
В других окнах всё работает, именно в окне юнити проблема.

(Уже пробовал как перезагрузку пк, так и переустановку (через хаб))

Answer (score 0):

По описанию похоже или на корапт проэкта или на глюк самого юнити.

Попробуй обновить версию юнити.

Если не поможет, пересмотри есть ли на сцене  Event System.

Если не поможет - экспортни весь проэкт в ассет, а потом импортируй его в новосозданный проэкт.

Еще виндовс попробуй обновить - лишним не будет)

Comment: Это происходит даже в новом проекте, именно в редакторе (я на английской раскладке не могу даже координаты объекта поменять). Винда недавно ток обновилась. Проверял 3 версии юнити (18, 19 и 20 года), везде одно и тоже

Comment: тогда идей нет .